# rails server stops when i try to use "rails s"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails. When I build my app and try to run the server with `rails s` I get the following:

```
**radu@radu ~/rails_projects/first_app $ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 3.2.6 application starting in development on http:// 0.0.0.0:3000

=> Call with -d to detach

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

[2012-07-06 15:30:09] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1

[2012-07-06 15:30:09] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [i686-linux]

[2012-07-06 15:30:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8179 port=3000**
```

Then it stops for no apparent reason and T can't do anything except close it with ctrl+c.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to be. Server will print logs here later. Try opening `localhost:3000` in your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rails s` **runs the web server** that ships with rails.  All that does is sit in the background as a process and listens for incoming web requests on port 3000 on localhost.  Run it again and go to `http://localhost:3000`.

**Are you expecting more of a console** where you can interact with your application?  If so, what you want is `rails console` which allows you to interact with your app.  You can write and run code - really useful for trying out things on the fly before you commit them to code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really expecting a magick in rails. Open the browser and open localhost:3000, come back here and check the logs. You need to hit the server in order to get the logs and this is how it works.